# I get an attribute error when I run this program. I'm working with kivy module in python and am not sure of how to overcome this

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

So, here's the python file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout 
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager 
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.graphics import *


class Login(Widget):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    print(name, email)

kv = Builder.load_file("test_page.kv")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

And here's the kivy file, that I've saved as 'test_page.kv'

```
<SmoothButton@Button>:
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''
    back_color: (1,0,1,1)
    border_radius: [18]
    canvas.before:
        color:
            rgba: self.back_color

        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: self.border_radius
Login:
    name: name
    email: email

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width-200, root.height-200
        pos: 100, 100

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Label:  
                text: "Name"
            TextInput:
                id: name
                multiline: False

            Label:
                text: "Email"
            TextInput:
                id: email
                multiline: False

        SmoothButton:
            text: "Submit"
            back_color: (0,0.95,0.105,0)
```

I want to build a page which has a rounded rectangular submit button... I watched several tutorials on how to do the same but got no efficient results. I'd be thankful if anyone could guide me through this.

Comment: When you get an error traceback, always post that as part of the question. It includes information to help debug the problem, saving everybody time.

Answer (score 0):

In your `canvas.before`, `Color` must be capitalized:

```
canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: self.back_color
```